# Is the X-Men: Evolution Toad immune to his own slime?

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit, x-men-evolution

In the animated TV show X-Men: Evolution, there is a two-part episode called 'The HeX Factor', where Wanda Maximoff (the Scarlet Witch) is added to the Brotherhood by Mystique to give them more firepower against the X-Men.

Upon seeing Quicksilver, she goes into a rage, attacking them, only to be attacked by Avalanche and Toad. When Toad spits a wad of slime at her, she reverses it in mid-air, causing it to strike him in the face and explode.

However, when this has happened to others, the slime has stuck, blinding them. Is Toad protected from his powers, or was this just a random event?

Answer (score 4):

It's generally accepted in the Marvel universe that mutants are immune to their own powers. Hence why Cyclops doesn't blast his eye sockets out every time he uses his powers. There are exceptions, but they usually become real plot points.

Comment: So is Toad an exception or not?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as how he's able to open his mouth despite it being filled with the stuff, I'd say he's immune to it.

Answer (score 0):

> When Toad spits a wad of slime at her, she reverses it in mid-air, causing it to strike him in the face and explode.

The explosion is a result of Wanda ' s Hex magic.

As a general rule, mutant powers are sulfur sustainable, as long as the mutant has his power it's mutations won't affect them (Iceman become physical ice, Banshee not blowing his own eardrums out, Bishop not exploding, one mutant that has a missing jaw dying when depowered). Physical powers are slightly different, as the physical item created is just a regular item. Ice Man could in theory impale himself with ice if caught unaware, Angel can fly up and then dive bomb to death, Avalanche could bury himself.

Toad's spit would likely still affect him when he spits it out and it starts to harden. It's just hard or stupid to hit yourself with your own spit. If someone copies his powers, they would both affect each other.

Comment: As for proof, I don't recall a time where rogue stole his powers or Jean reversed it mid flight,  so common sense applies